# Comparing a value with a difference that should be same is not

Tags: excel, excel-formula, rounding, precision, excel-2013

I'm using Excel 2013 on Windows 7.

I did some Excel data checking using basic IF and some operators. And I encountered an issue that give me inconsistency in the result. I'm checking is:

```
1.24 = 66.64 - 65.4
```

Below is the formula I used and the result should be mathematically EQUAL, but it gives me NOT EQUAL:

```
=IF(1.24 = 66.64 - 65.4, "EQUAL", "NOT EQUAL")     ;Result: NOT EQUAL
```

I tried to modify the data slightly to:

```
=IF(1.24 = 56.64 - 55.4, "EQUAL", "NOT EQUAL")     ;Result: EQUAL
```

and I'm surprised that it return the correct result.

Is this a bug, and if so, is there any workaround I can use for similar checking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of a bug - I suspect due to the limited precision, that in turn is a result of representing floating point numbers. The way [ROUND](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/round.php) this is to force some approximation, say:

```
=IF(ROUND(1.24,2) = ROUND(56.64 - 55.4,2), "EQUAL", "NOT EQUAL")
```

Answer (score 1):

Excel's [15 digit precision floating point errors](http://blogs.office.com/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/) do not happen for every number combination; only when a decimal is rounded up or down due to a limited num ber of decimals. Time values are notorious for these errors.

So your first set of numbers (`1.24 = 66.64 - 65.4`) generates a floating point error from being digitally rounded off at some point. The second set of numbers (`1.24 = 56.64 - 55.4`) happily does not exhibit this behavior.

[image: 15 digit precision error]

You can see in the preceding image that is you expand the decimals enough the floating point error becomes apparent.

More at [Floating-point arithmetic may give inaccurate results in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/78113).